# How to change key-bindings in firefox?

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys, vim, firefox-extensions

`Firefox` constantly keep moving `platformHTMLBindings.xml` when it upgrade.
I want to replace it to support `vi` key-bindings. But I cannot find it any more.

```
sudo find / -name platformHTMLBindings.xml -o -name toolkit.jar -o -name omni.jar
```

Thanks for your help.

#### Edit:

I finally found it. It's called `omni.ja` now.

---

This is my editing to `platformHTMLBindings.xml`:

```
  <binding id="browser">
    <handlers>
      <handler event="keypress" key=" " modifiers="shift" command="cmd_scrollPageUp" />
      <handler event="keypress" key=" " command="cmd_scrollPageDown" />

      <handler event="keypress" key="k" command="cmd_scrollLineUp" />
      <handler event="keypress" key="j" command="cmd_scrollLineDown" />
      <handler event="keypress" key="h" command="cmd_scrollLeft" />
      <handler event="keypress" key="l" command="cmd_scrollRight" />
```

After Editing, I restart firefox, and clear the cache.
`chrome://global/content/platformHTMLBindings.xml` is correct.
But the `j/k/h/l` shortcuts didn't work.

Comment: Submit it as an answer instead of comment if your question is solved so that people knew that it is answered.

Comment: @mac Haven't solved yet. Because after changing `platformHTMLBindings.xml`, nothing happened.

Comment: Now if you change `omni.ja`, Firefox recognizes this and says that it needs to restart

Comment: @kev where did you find commands like `cmd_scrollLineUp` from?

Comment: @hatter I use `vimperator` now. It works very well!

Comment: @kev I just needed this 'jk-scrolling' functionality. I didn't need all of Vim's keybindings. So this question exactly catered my need.

Comment: @hatter You can read this doc: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Emacs_Keybindings_%28Firefox%29

Comment: But this solution has a problem. `omni.ja` is not preseved across Firefox updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to disable/enable an add-on to reload `/usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja`.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in a GUI, you can use the extension "[Menu Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/%22Menu%20Wizard%22)", usage [is described here](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-customize-shortcut-keys-hotkeys-in-mozilla-firefox/). Another GUI, supporting more and different actions, is provided with the extension "[Key config](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/key-config/)".

Comment: The first addon no longer works with new Firefox. From addon's page: "Unfortunately, WebExtensions (the new API for Firefox 57+) does not have the functionality for the correct operation of this addon in Firefox.
So this addon will no longer work with the release of Firefox 57 in November 2017!
This is the inevitable change in Firefox - all Xul-addons will die out in Firefox 57" https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/